# example of infinite group that maschke's theorem is not hold

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Show by giving an an example that Maschke's theorem does not hold for all infinite groups.

Comment: Maybe you should try the simplest infinite group $\mathbb{Z}$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \Bbb Z$ act on $\Bbb C^2$ via $n\cdot (z_1,z_2) := \begin{pmatrix}1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{pmatrix} = (z_1 + nz_2, z_2)$, and consider the $G$-invariant subspace $Span(1,0)$.