# Surjection onto subrepresentation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $(V,\tau)$ be a representation of $G$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. $\tau: G \longrightarrow GL(V)$ is a group homomorphism. Then we can identify each element of $G$ as a linear map $T \longrightarrow T$. Let $W \subset V$, $W$ is a subrepresentation if for all $g \in G, w \in W$ we have $wg \in W$.

A representation homomorphism: $\theta: V_1 \longrightarrow V_2$ is a linear map such that $\theta(v_1g) = \theta(v_1)g$.

Here is my question, Let $V$ be a representation of $G$. Let $W \subset V$ be a subrepresentation. Then obviously there exists an injective homomorphism $\alpha: W \longrightarrow V$.

But does there exist $\beta: V \longrightarrow W$ such that $\beta$ is a surjective homomorphism between representations?

If $G$ is finite, then we can simply use Maschke's theorem, then take the projection map as $\beta$. But what if $G$ is infinite, my intuition is that $\beta$ might not exist.

I tried to play around with the example given here [example of infinite group that maschke's theorem is not hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635847/example-of-infinite-group-that-maschkes-theorem-is-not-hold).

I know that the projection map does not exist, but how about just surjection?

Comment: Why isn't the example given there good for you ?

Comment: Im trying to generalize things

Comment: What do you mean by "Im trying to generalize things"? The linked example gives an explicit case where $\beta$ does not exist.

Comment: @DavidHill well we know that the projection map does not exist, but how about the surjection map?

Comment: What do you mean "just surjection"? What else would a projection be?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft does there exists a surjective homomorphism $\beta V \longrightarrow W$? Where $\beta$ does not need to be a projection.

Comment: @Tobias:  Here's a guess.  A projection must satisfy $\beta^2 = \beta$, but a general surjection need not.

Comment: @JasonDeVito That property only makes sense for endomorphisms, in which case being surjective implies being an isomorphism since these are finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Tobias:  I agree it only makes sense for endomorphisms, but I don't understand your second clause.  For example, if $G = S^1$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^4$ as the sum of four standard reps, then the map $\mathbb{C}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$  which has kernel the first factor, and permutes the other three factors by a non-involution is a surjective, not an isomorphism, and not a projection (according to my guess above).

Comment: @JasonDeVito I meant that once it is both an endomorphism and a surjection, it becomes an isomorphism.

Comment: @Tobias:  Oh yes, duh.  My map, thought of as an endomorphism, is not surjective.  Woops!